# What is WASM Engine and how to Embed WASM Engine?

Tags: webassembly, rust-wasm

Is there any concept of Wasm Engine and how to embed it, show that we can run any program which is in web assembly?

Comment: You can just run WASM in the browser directly. You don't need any kind of specialised hosting for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787083/what-engine-does-webassembly-use